# Alire fails with error when building project

Tags: git, ada

I am following the steps here https://pico-doc.synack.me/ to create a simple Ada program to flash a LED on the Raspberry Pi but have come across an issue when building with Alire.

Using the above steps, running either:

```
alr with pico_bsp
```

or

```
alr build
```

the following error is returned:

```
error: Could not add community index: Command ["git", "submodule", "update", "--init", "--recursive", "--progress"] exited with code 1
```

Is there something missing from the above git command that Alire runs?
(sudo-running these commands returns the same error)

Searching for this exact error yields zero results.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and have the git command that comes with that.

Any ideas/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is because Ubuntu 16.04 includes a fairly old version of git that does not support the `--progress` flag to the `git submodule update` command. I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/alire-project/alire/issues/966) against Alire to see if we might be able to remove this flag.

In the meantime, I'd recommend upgrading git to the latest version. You may also want to consider a more recent Ubuntu version as Alire hasn't been tested extensively on older releases. Alire's integration tests are currently run on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Updating git to the latest version worked, thank you! Building works up to linking phase and then it dies with "version `GLIBC_2.27' not found". I guess, like you say, time to upgrade to a more recent version. :)

Answer (score 3):

I *think* you need to say

```
alr index --update-all
```

`--update-all` is a bit misleading, but given that the error message mentions "index" it was the only likely thing in `alr index --help` (you find the possible commands, e.g. "index" here, by just `alr --help`).

Comment: Tried that but got the same error. - Thank you.